# My question is about getting an internal div to be hidden by changing the width of another div set to hide overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element, which contains an svg, in a school project that currently I can control the width% of with a slider.
My question is that I would like to be able to control the width% of a div which surrounds this one with its overflow set to hidden as such to hide and reveal the svg inside as if opening and closing a curtain.

here is the css

```
svg {
  width: 100%;  
  height: auto;        
}

#svgDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#internalsvg {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

and the js

```
function updateWidth(slideAmount) {
    var svgDiv = document.getElementById("svgDiv");
    svgDiv.style.width = slideAmount + "%";
}
```

This still makes the entire div width% change, when I just want the outside div to increase and decrease in width, hiding the internal div.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `#internalsvg` is the parent of `svg`, and `#svgDiv` is the parent of `#internalsvg`, then altering the width of `#svgDiv` will change the widths of all its children, as `#internalsvg` and `svg` have percentage based widths.

When you set the width of an element to a percentage (in your case 100%), it calculates that width based on its immediate parent. An element with width `100%` will be exactly as wide as its immediate parent. Therefore the width of `#internalsvg` is calculated to be 100% of the width of `#svgDiv` *whatever `#svgDiv`'s width is changed to*.

If, for example, the parent of `#svgDiv` was 1000 pixels wide then when the page first loads `svgDiv` would have a displayed width that was 100% of 1000 px wide (so 1000 px). `internalsvg` would be 100% of its parent, `#svgDiv`, so it would also be 1000 px wide. Now let's say the CSS width of `#svgDiv` is changed with your slider to 70%. The width of `#svgDiv` is then 70% of 1000 pixels, so it will be displayed as 700 px wide. `#internalsvg` is still 100% the width of `#svgDiv`, which is now 100% of 700 px, so the displayed width of `#internalsvg` will also shrink to 700 px.

You need your `#internalsvg` element to stay the same width as the parent of `#svgDiv`, regardless of any CSS width changes to `#svgDiv`. There are a few ways to do this, but since `#svgDiv` starts with a width of 100%, one way might be to use JavaScript to calculate the width of `#svgDiv` in pixels when the page has loaded and fix the width of `#internalsvg` to that. You would add the following code to your script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var internalsvg = document.getElementById( "internalsvg" );
    var svgDiv = document.getElementById( "svgDiv" );
    internalsvg.style.width = svgDiv.offsetWidth + "px";
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I have added your function to my script, but it seems that the `#svgDiv` width changes just fine, but the `overflow: hidden;` still has no effect as to hide the `#internalsvg` and `<svg>` @jla

Comment: @TimothyMiller could you please add the HTML to your question

Comment: Got it working! As soon as I removed the `position: fixed;` from `#internalsvg` it now appears as if a curtain is opening and closing over the svg with the slider. Note that I also had to add `height: 100%;` to the `#svgDiv` to get this to work